# How do i open a link in js with html code

Tags: javascript, html, url

Following js code refreshing the page to the url, but i wanna make it open in a new tab.

````
    case"example1":  case"example2":
     l.after('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://example.com" /> Opening...'); ```
Can anyone help me about that?
````

Answer (score -1):

Steps for opening a link in a new tab:

1. Create an `a` element
2. Set the href ( `"https://example.com"` )
3. Set `target` to `"_blank"`
4. Click on the link

**Code**:

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Open</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  link = document.createElement("a")
  link.href = "https://example.com"
  link.target = "_blank"
  link.click()
}
</script>
```